# CSS - Underline text but ignore the spaces

Tags: css, space, underline

I have a couple of links that have a margin-left of 3px. These links are underlined and look like that:

```
<a href='#'>
    test
</a>
```

Unfortunately, there are spaces inside the link and I'm not able to remove these space since I don't have access to the HTML code. These spaces are also underlined, which I'm not happy with. Is there any way to remove them without changing the HTML?

Here is a fiddle that shows my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/e8quz/

Update:
Here is a picture, what I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: dont think you can do that without removing the actual spaces or editing the html in other way.

Comment: So you'd like to "hide" the original HTML and display a different HTML with your specific formatting...is that right? How are you accessing the original HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spaces come from the line-breaks (well-known from the `display:inline-block` problematic).

So make your `a` elements `display: block` and float them to the left.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8quz/1/)

PS: The `display:block` is "redundant", as `float` normally already sets the display property of the respective element to "block". But it do no harm ...!

Comment: just setting `display:inline-block` works great. Using `float` sometimes is not suitable.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, like always in web design - it depends! But be aware, that it gives not the same result. Using `display:inline-block` gives you still an additional space (depending on the respective markup).

Comment: could you please make some fiddle showing that `display:inline-block` will fail? because for the OP's HTML code, it works.

Comment: Here is the case showing that using `float` is not really suitable http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/e8quz/3/ , while if using `display:inline-block` we have the expected result http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/e8quz/4/

Comment: @KingKing No, you got me wrong. It does not "fail". It just gives you a (slightly) different result, as the line-breaks will cause some "extra space". That's all I meant. ;-)

Comment: @KingKing Sure you can "construct" hundreds of use cases where any other CSS is required. But here we are talking about the given markup (by the OP) and "I don't have access to the HTML code" makes it really unlikely that the "float solution" won't work in his case. And there are also use cases where it is the other way round, where the "diswplay: inline-block" method has "unwanted side effects".

Answer (score 2):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BWc2U/2/

This will also solve the issue. There is no need to make them floats, with the floats you need to clear the floats otherwise all content after will also be floated etc...

```
a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of that and I pointed it out at my question: "there are spaces inside the link ". The problem is: I can't change the HTML as you did. I just have access to the CSS files.

Answer (score 1):

You can just float the links to make the white space disappear without editing the html

```
a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8quz/2/