# Setting paragraph to inline-block is causing odd (_ underscore) to randomly appear in text?

Tags: html, css, display

Here is the fiddle of the behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/gyjnaovs/1/

You can see a random _ in the text.

If you remove the `inline-block` from `#auth-google-text` the underscore will disappear.  Very odd behavior.

What is causing this and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: In this case, `inline-block` is no different from `inline`, which is the default behavior for `<a>` tags, in which whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs) are collapsed to a single space, and underlined because they are part of the hyperlink. To remove the space, delete the whitespace around the `<img>` tag. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182904/css-underline-text-but-ignore-the-spaces

Comment: I understand 100% of what you are saying.  The odd part is that this "space" that is underlined does not render unless I change the styling of its adjacent element to inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

#auth-google-link is rendering as anchor tag and by default **text-decoration: underscore** is set to it.

You can remove **text-decoration** and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the unwanted space or ***underscore*** in your text by removing the line breaks in HTML the code... The line breaks in your HTML code are creating this underscore.

Instead of

```
<a id='auth-google-link' href="/auth/google">
   <img id='auth-google-image' src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRw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%0D%0Ac3ZnPg==' />
</a>
<p id="auth-google-text">
   hi
</p>
```

Remove those line breaks ***INSIDE OF THE A*** tag...

```html
<a id='auth-google-link' href="/auth/google"><img id='auth-google-image' src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRw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%0D%0Ac3ZnPg==' /></a>
       <p id="auth-google-text">hi</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a85xbgfq/

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block` to `#auth-google-link`:

```
#auth-google-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also see [CSS - Underline text but ignore the spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182904/css-underline-text-but-ignore-the-spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Because you used anchor tag. use `text-decoration: none;` property for remove underline in anchor tags.

```
a{
text-decoration: none;}
```